# Cron is a spammer, how do I stop it?

Tags: apt, cron

So, I'm being stuck with a very peculiar spambot: `cron`.

Every day, I'm presented with the following e-mail:

> ```
> /etc/cron.daily/apt:
> FATAL -> Failed to fork.
> ```

What would be causing this error? My `/etc/cron.daily/apt` is the same that comes with the default installation, so it's obviously something else.

I'm not concerned about cron sending me mails (as it gives me a lot of useful issues/data). I just want to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: [Mandatory xkcd.](https://xkcd.com/1728/)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I clicked this question just because I want to see the mandatory XKCD

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Is the system running ouf of memory?**

You can have a look in `/var/log/syslog` to see if you get any `OOM` (Out Of Memory) messages during the time of day when `/etc/cron.daily/apt` is running.

`/etc/cron.daily/apt` is executed at 06:25, but there is a random sleep in the apt script, so it might be up to 1800 seconds later

The command `free -m` will also be able to tell you how much free memory you have, and `vmstat 5` will be able to show you if you have a lot of swapping, or memory movement going on.

If this is the case you might look into adding more *swap*, adding more *memory*, or find if you have any unnecessary processes running that takes all of your memory. (A reboot in the case of a memory leak)

**Run apt manually?**

Have you tried running `/etc/cron.daily/apt` manually to see if you can any more warnings/errors?

If you are running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS you'll find a call for `random_sleep` subroutine on `line 425`. Add a `#` on this line to not have it sleep before a run.

On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS it is `line 423`. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS should not have this file as far as I can see.

Run `/etc/cron.daily/apt` as root like this:

```
root@hostname:~# /etc/cron.daily/apt
```

Or with `sudo` like this:

```
username@hostname:~$ sudo /etc/cron.daily/apt
```

There might be some interesting errors to point to you the right direction, or try looking in the `/var/log/syslog` file for anything suspicious.

Comment: You can get even more information by running the script with trace on: `sudo sh -x /etc/cron.daily/apt`